# How do I install TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, cmd

I have tried to install TensorFlow using `pip install tensorflow` but command prompt threw an error saying

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: none)

> ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow

Comment: What version of Python?  What platform?  What version of the platform?  For instance, tensorflow doesn't yet have support for Python 3.10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure that the version of Python and the version of Tensorflow are not in conflict.
Check this first!

```
>>> python3 --version
```

Make sure it is not the latest one(like 3.10). It takes time for Other libraries to support the latest versions.

Then go to [TensorFlow PIP history page](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/#history) and look for the compatible version.

Preferably use Anaconda for package management and install any big Frameworks/libraries in [virtual environments](https://uoa-eresearch.github.io/eresearch-cookbook/recipe/2014/11/20/conda/)